# change color by text in css3

Tags: css

i came across the following code. this code should automatically change the color of the text by specific word or other characters. the code does not work for me, is really supposed to work or is it not true

```
#text [all "(" ] {
  color: blue;
}
```

The code is at the bottom of [this page](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/82654-how-can-you-highlight-text-multiple-colors-within-textarea/).

Comment: if you read below the code on the page you linked to it says `That's not the exact css code, but you get the idea. Google is your friend.`

Comment: I don't think this property exists... Well if yes it is not well documented there

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to do that, you need to do something awful like giving each character a span with itself as the class, or (my preference) use Javascript. [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) is a great library that can let you apply classes or CSS styling based on the values of variables or functions (among many other useful things), so if you have a table and want negative numbers to appear in red, your `<TD>` tags would look something like:

```
<td data-bind="with: someObject, text: someProperty, css: {'isRed':someProperty()<0}"></td>
```

and you'd need a JavaScript object like

```
var someObject = {
    someProperty: ko.observable(0);
}
```

Then you just need to apply your Knockout bindings and you're set!